# create a week-day/weekend time series dataframe based on a daily time series dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have created a dataframe with time series information, for instance

```
Time      daily-bill
2012-01-01   200
2012-01-02  300
2012-01-03   100
2012-01-04    500
….
```

I would like to  create another time series dataframe based on the above time series. How to do it in Pandas?

```
Time(weekday-and-weekend)                       total-bill
Monday-Friday
Weekend
Monday-Friday
Weekend
Monday-Friday
Weekend
```

In other words, the time step will be a continuous sequence of `weekday` and `weekend`.  The `weekday` consists of `Monday to Friday`; while the `weekend` consists of `Saturday` and `Sunday`. The `total-bill` column will store the sum of bills happened in the corresponding days, these information comes from the existing time series.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print (df)
        Time  daily-bill
0 2012-01-01         200
1 2012-01-02         300
2 2012-01-03         100
3 2012-01-04         500
4 2012-01-05         200
5 2012-01-06         300
6 2012-01-07         100
7 2012-01-08         500
8 2012-01-09         500

arr = np.where(df['Time'].dt.weekday > 4, 'Weekend','Monday-Friday')

s = pd.Series(arr)
s1 = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()

df = (df['daily-bill'].groupby([s1,s.rename('Time')])
                     .sum()
                     .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                     .reset_index())
print (df)
            Time  daily-bill
0        Weekend         200
1  Monday-Friday        1400
2        Weekend         600
3  Monday-Friday         500
```

**Explanation**:

1. First create `Series` by [`weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).
2. Then create another `Series` which is create by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of shifted `s` by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) for distinguish consecutive values
3. Aggregate `sum` and remove first level by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`

**Details**:

```
print (s)
0          Weekend
1    Monday-Friday
2    Monday-Friday
3    Monday-Friday
4    Monday-Friday
5    Monday-Friday
6          Weekend
7          Weekend
8    Monday-Friday
dtype: object

print (s1)
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
8    4
dtype: int32
```

EDIT:

If firts column of input `DataFrame` is `DatetimeIndex`:

```
print (df)
            daily-bill
Time                  
2012-01-01         200
2012-01-02         300
2012-01-03         100
2012-01-04         500
2012-01-05         200
2012-01-06         300
2012-01-07         100
2012-01-08         500
2012-01-09         500

arr = np.where(df.index.weekday > 4, 'Weekend','Monday-Friday')

s = pd.Series(arr, index=df.index)
s1 = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()

df = (df['daily-bill'].groupby([s1,s.rename('Time')])
                     .sum()
                     .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                     .reset_index())
print (df)
            Time  daily-bill
0        Weekend         200
1  Monday-Friday        1400
2        Weekend         600
3  Monday-Friday         500
```